# iOS 13 Silent Mode Notification/Alert

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS 13 (or maybe before) Apple started to indicate the switch tosilent mode with a novel notification type that remindes slightly to androids toasts. Does anyone know how to reproduce that? Is there a new kind of alert or something like that or do you still have to do that manually?
[image: image from https://www.macrumors.com/]

Comment: is not possible to display that or anything similar to that. you don't have access to customise notifications view. if you want to show that inside your app, that another story and can be made.

Comment: It would be great to have so stylish toast messages. And at the same time, they can be reserved by Apple, so that users associate them only with system notifications ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are no public APIs that Apple provides that you could use to create a custom notification like that at the moment.